# Custom state store provider for Apache Spark on Mesos

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, spark-structured-streaming

I've written a custom state store and state store provider for Apache Spark 2.3.0 and tried to deploy the job using the additional argument:

```
--conf spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass=com.sample.state.CustomStateStoreProvider
```

For running Spark jobs I use Marathon and Mesos, and the job fails just after starting with the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sample.state.CustomStateStoreProvider 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreProvider$.create(StateStore.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreWriter$class.stateStoreCustomMetrics(statefulOperators.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreWriter$class.metrics(statefulOperators.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec.metrics$lzycompute(statefulOperators.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec.metrics(statefulOperators.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$.fromSparkPlan(SparkPlanInfo.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$.fromSparkPlan(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$.fromSparkPlan(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$.fromSparkPlan(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$.fromSparkPlan(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$.fromSparkPlan(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$$anonfun$fromSparkPlan$1.apply(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$.fromSparkPlan(SparkPlanInfo.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:474)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
```

Here is the command to run the job:

```
/spark/bin/spark-submit \
    --repositories "http://127.0.0.1:80/sbt-all" \
    --packages com.sample:pipelines:0.1.0 \
    --class com.sample.TestApplication \
    --conf spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass=com.sample.state.CustomStateStoreProvider \
    /spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

Both of classes `com.sample.TestApplication` and `com.sample.state.CustomStateStoreProvider` are located in the `com.sample:pipelines:0.1.0` package, and I already checked this several times. Without the `spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass` parameter the applications starts and runs well.

I already tried to submit the job using additional class-paths for the driver and executors and using the `--jars` parameter with the JAR located in HDFS or through HTTP.

P.S.: I don't have any problem when I try to start the job locally and everything works well in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in general, it's needed to enclose the value of the `spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass` parameter into quotes: `--conf spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass="com.sample.state.CustomStateStoreProvider"`. Without it, the space after the value will be included to the value and Spark will look for the `com.sample.state.CustomStateStoreProvider` class (with the space symbol at the end of line) and won't be able to find it. Everything else works well at all :)

Comment: Hi, Alex can you please paste your code sample for the state store, I also  had an issue with HDFS state storm OOM when joining streams on spark 2.3.

Comment: @ArnonRodman Hi, I'll ask my manager about it and if everything is ok I'd like to share my code as a library.

Comment: @ArnonRodman Well, now you can use some code from my repository https://github.com/chermenin/spark-states as an example.

Comment: Thx @AlexChermenin I'm trying both ways flatMapGroupsWithState/ mapwithstate vs Spark 2.3 high-level API stream to stream Join with your code( rocks...)